# Spring security return 403 if request macher not pass

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Is it possible that if `AndRequestMatcher` which checks if url is `orders/notify` and request comes from proper IP return 403? Below configuration always passes which shouldnt if IP address don't match.

```
    @Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    AntPathRequestMatcher antRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/orders/notify/**", HttpMethod.POST.name());

    AndRequestMatcher andMatcher = new AndRequestMatcher(new HeaderIPAddressRequestMatcher(ips), antRequestMatcher);

    http.cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .sessionManagement().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(andMatcher).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
    http.headers()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity().maxAgeInSeconds(YEAR.toSeconds()).includeSubDomains(false);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I achieve it by creating custom filter:

```
public class IPHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    private final List<String> ips;

    public IPHeaderFilter(List<String> ips) {
        this.ips = ips;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        var request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        var response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        AntPathRequestMatcher antRequestMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/orders/notify/**", HttpMethod.POST.name());

        if (antRequestMatcher.matches(request)) {
            HeaderIPAddressRequestMatcher ipHeaderMatcher = new HeaderIPAddressRequestMatcher(ips);
            if (!ipHeaderMatcher.matches(request)) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            } else {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```